# ZipArchive->deleteName not always working on Debian

Tags: php, symfony, php-ziparchive

I have a zip archive with a file "file.txt" and some others.
I would like to extract this file and then delete it from the archive.

So I did that :

```
chmod( $file_path, 0777); 
if ($zip->open( $file_path ) === TRUE) 
{
    if( $zip->extractTo( $dir, array('file.txt') ) )
    {
         $zip->deleteName('file.txt');
    }
}
```

It works on my computer (Windows) but when I run it on my server (Debian), it doesn't for some archive (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't). Do you know why ? Is it possible to do something like this ?

```
$zip->deleteName('%file.txt%');
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, if I extract the zip file and make an other one, it works. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to permission, chmod() may not work as you expect, and when you create the archive yourself by extracting and archiving again it work because it got the right permissions already.

> The current user is the user under which PHP runs. It is probably not
>   the same user you use for normal shell or FTP access. The mode can be
>   changed only by user who owns the file on most systems.

So check if your user which runs PHP is the one owning the folder.